# how to check condition in first class on the string of second class?

Tags: iphone

I want to check the conditon in my first class on the base of second class string.i mean i have a string mystr in second class which contain the value like "sarab".Now i want to use condition in first class that if mystr="anything..".But i am not able to check the condtion.I dont know how to use second class string.Actually i have made one method in second class where i store the string value.Please tell me how i check the value of the string.My second class code is like that:

```
second.m

(void)mystrmethod
{
  mystr=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
  mystr=@"sarab";
  NSLog(@" %@ ",mystr);
}
```

Now i want to check this str in my first class.
Thank you

Comment: are you making an object of second class in first class?

Comment: yes i am making object of second class in first class.

Answer (score 0):

make this string variable global. then u can use this.

Comment: my problem is that..after loading first class i perform some actions and when i click on button to show second class it will go on second class where i perform some action and after saving string value in a string i will again go back to my first class.Here i am trying to use the string of second class but when i use it it shows me the null string.....

Comment: if u take global variable this varibale have smae value in whole program when ever u change it

Comment: i think its the problem of intialization of the both classes.I mean when first class and second class intialize the string value is zero.And after that i set the string value  after intialization.But when i try to call from first class it will pick the null string from the second class.bcoz i set value in method in second class.I think it may like that.......m i right or wrong.....

Comment: when u set the value after that u print this string any ware in your program its have value what u set. declear like in the appdelegate nsstring *str; and use it.

Answer (score 0):

In your firstclass you need to import the second class like

```
#import "second.h"
```

and then you need to make an object of it like

```
Second *obj=[[Second alloc]init];
```

and then you can check the string value using

```
if{  [obj.mystr isEqualToString @"sarab"]}{
//then do something here
}
```

but all this work only if you define the string first and then compare it ..

hope this helps...

Comment: on second class where i perform some action and after saving string value in a string i will again go back to my first class.Here i am trying to use the string of second class but when i use it it shows me the null string.....

Comment: `Second *obj=[[Second alloc]init];` this line creates a new object,it will not give you the previously saved value.

Comment: That is what i wish to say .. he will have to create a class of type NSObject and then define the value there .. and then if he uses it to create an object ,it will contain the value in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your string in the appdelegate file and access it where ever you want using :

```
 appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        if([appDelegate.<yourString> isEqualToString:@"<compareString>"]){
NSLog(@"appDelegate.<yourString> = %@",appDelegate.<yourString>);
           }
```